# Suggestions for a SPI Master board which can be directly controlled through USB using C/C++?

Tags: microcontroller, spi, usb-device

I am trying to figure out a solution to control multiple SPI slaves directly through my software.

I am developing software in C/C++ for a hardware device that has an MCC USB-2637 DAQ board to acquire analog data. In my hardware, I have some digital potentiometers AD5292 which can be controlled using the SPI interface. However, the MCC USB-2637 does not provide an SPI interface. So, I am looking for a simple to use Board such as Arduino but with higher reliability as the device I am working on is going to last at least a decade.

I have looked a lot, but all I could find are MCUs that provide the SPI functionality, and all of them require me to write embedded software that I am not familiar with. I am looking for a device for which there is a C library available, just like MCC DAQ USB-2637 that I am using, where I can include the required header, .lib and .dll in my C++ project and control the device directly through USB using C commands. Can you recommend any such device? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Shopping is off-topic.

Comment: Can't you just bit-bang on the DIOs? You don't need to replicate all the SPI pins for each device. The MISO, MOSI, and CLK can be connected to all slave devices in parallel and then one SS pin for each device select. You have 24 DIO pins to work with.

Comment: So how reliable is an Arduino and how much more reliable you need?

Answer (score 1):

depending on how fast the interfacing must be you can use a [busPirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate)
this device is connected via usb emulating serial, so you should be able to controlling using serial port libraries in C/C++, here you have [an example](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/KS0074_serial_LCD) on how to operate it

Comment: Thanks! Interface speed is not a big concern.

Comment: Famous last words....

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like the Silicon Labs CP2130 Evaluation Kit. It can control up to 11 SPI slaves on a single USB port and has windows support.